# абстрактные классы и наследование

Tags: php

проверьте пожалуйста задание

1. Создайте базовый класс продукта.
2. Создайте три любых типа продукта (класса), в разных категориях;
3. Все продукты, кроме одного, имеют 10 процентную скидку и их цена должна выводиться с ней;
4. Один тип продукта - имеет скидку только в том случае, если его вес больше 10 килограмм;

Используйте примеси, интерфейсы или абстрактные классы в решении задачи.

Нормальный ли код для первого раза?

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset:utf-8');
error_reporting(-1);

abstract class Product{
    public $title;
    protected $price;
    public $weight;

    private $discount = 10;

    public function getDiscount(){
        return $this->discount;
    }

    public function getPrice(){
        return $this->price;
    }

    protected function getPriceDiscount(){
        if ($this->getDiscount()) {
            return round($this->price - ($this->price * $this->getDiscount()/100));
        }
        else {
            return $this->price;
        }
    }

    public function getFunGetPriceDiscount(){
        return $this->getPriceDiscount();
    }

    public function __construct($title, $price, $weight){
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->price = $price;
        $this->weight = $weight;
    }
}

class Planshet extends Product{}

class Potato extends Product{
    function getFunGetPriceDiscount(){
        if($this->weight > 10000){
            return parent::getFunGetPriceDiscount();
        }
        else{
            return $this->getPrice();
        }
    }
}

class Jacket extends Product{}


$planshet = new Planshet('Планшет', 2000, 400);
$potato = new Potato('Картошка', 700, 12000);
$jacket = new Jacket('Куртка', 700, 2000);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

            echo $planshet->title . ' цена без скидки ' . $planshet->getPrice() . ', со скидкой ' . $planshet->getFunGetPriceDiscount();
            echo '<br>';
            echo $potato->title . ' цена без скидки ' . $potato->getPrice() . ', со скидкой ' . $potato->getFunGetPriceDiscount();
            echo '<br>';
            echo $jacket->title. ' цена ' . $jacket->getPrice();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: тот случай, когда MVC уместился в один файл :(

Comment: в смысле? я не понял

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса, что значит нормальный? Нормальный = работающий? Или нормальный = по стандартам psr1/2? Или нормальный = примут ли у вас задание?

Comment: Я так понимаю, вы это написали в рамках обучения. Я бы на вашем месте сделал бы ещё 2 варианта, через интерфейс и через трейты. В целях обучения.

Comment: @DivMan обычно всегда пытаются разделить модель данных (использеумые классы), логику их обработки (обработка входных параметров, создание, в данном случае экземпляров) и представления (генерация html) на разные, к примеру, файлы. У вас же все в одной куче.

Comment: @teran я не знаю, как правильно разделить